# Passing variables into awk from bash

Tags: bash, awk, ubuntu-12.04

I am writing a shell script file in which I have to print certain columns of a file.  So I try to use awk.  The column numbers are calculated in the script.  Nprop is a variable in a for loop, that changes from 1 to 8.

```
avg=1+3*$nprop
awk -v a=$avg '{print $a " " $a+1 " " $a+2}' $filename5 >> neig5.dat
```

I have tried the following also:

```
awk -v a=$avg '{print $a " " $(a+1) " " $(a+2) }' $filename5 >> neig5.dat
```

This results in printing the first three columns all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
avg=1+3*$nprop
```

This will set `$avg` to `1+3*4`, literally, if `$prop` is 4 for instance. You should be evaluating that expression:

```
avg=$(( 1+3*$nprop ))
```

And use the version of the `awk` script with parenthesis.

Comment: Don't do that, just pass nprop to awk and calculate the average in the BEGIN section.

Answer (score 2):

This single `awk` script is a translation of what you want:

```
awk '{j=0;for(i=4;i<=25;i=3*++j+1)printf "%s %s %s ",$i,$(i+1),$(i+2);print ""}'
```

You don't need to parse your file 8 times in a shell loop just parse it once with `awk`.

Comment: That could indeed be better I think. (Unless `$filename5` changes at each iteration, but that doesn't _appear_ to be the case.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BEGIN{ }` block to create a couple of awk variables:

```
avg=$((1+3*$nprop))

awk -v a=$avg 'BEGIN{ap1=a+1;ap2=a+2} {print $a " " $ap1 " " $ap2}' $filename5 >> neig5.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v n="$nprop" 'BEGIN{x=3*n} {a=x; print $++a, $++a, $++a}' file
```

If you just want your seed value (nprop) to increment on every pass of the file and process the file 8 times, get rid of your external loop and just do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=2;i<=8;i++) ARGV[++ARGC] = ARGV[1]} {a=3*NR/FNR; print $++a, $++a, $++a}' file
```

In GNU awk you can replace NR/FNR with ARGIND.