# variable passing -v in awk not working

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Inside a shell script I'm trying to pass a variable to awk:

Say I have

```
Y=113
```

I would like to go trough a file (bigfile), and if the variable Y matches on a line, print a few columns.

If I use

```
awk  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/113/){print $1, $2, $3, $4}}}' < bigfile > x_113_list
```

I get the desired result

However, if I try

```
Y=113
awk -v y="$Y" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/y/){print $1, $2, $3, $4}}}' < bigfile > x_"$Y"_list
```

I get nothing. (this is the case even if I try it on the command line) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing variables into awk from bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340775/passing-variables-into-awk-from-bash)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott The titles are similar, but the questions are totally different.

Comment: @Barmar The code looked similar also, my bad.

Comment: What OS are you using? There are two different ways variables are passed in awk. One is using the `-v` option at the beginning. The second is to put them at the end. It depends upon the OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables aren't substituted inside a regular expression in `awk`. `/y/` always means a match of the single character `y`.

What you may want to do is use the `index` function, as in: `if (index($i, y) != 0 ...`

Answer (score 4):

Just drop the forward slashes around y:

```
{if($i~y){print $1, $2, $3, $4}}
```

~ /y/ would match against the character y, ~ y matches against the variable y, which seems what you want.