# How to pass a bash script variable to AWK using $() and collect the ouput

Tags: bash, awk

The problem is in following:

```
solaris:~/src/brk$ cat .file
one xxx 123
two yyy 123

three bbb 321

four xyz 123
```

Script:

```
solaris:~/src/brk$ cat scr.sh
... 
PATH="dist/"
LINE=$(awk '/^[ \t]*$/{next} /^[ \t]*#/{next} {printf $2" "}' .file)
echo "LINE=$LINE"
...
```

Output:

```
xxx yyy bbb xyz
```

I want the following output:

```
dist/xxx dist/yyy dist/bbb dist/xyz
```

How can I modify awk expression to get the desired output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing variables into awk from bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340775/passing-variables-into-awk-from-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set variables in `awk` using the `-v` switch:

```
PATHI="dist/"
LINE=$(awk -v p=$PATHI '/^[ \t]*$/{next} /^[ \t]*#/{next} {printf p$2" "}' .file)
```

Comment: Ops, thank you. I thought -v won't work inside $() but it works. Then this question is duplicate of duplicate and I probably need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `PATH` as a variable name! That is already used by the shell. Always use lower-case variables in bash for this reason: the ones used by the shell are always uppercase. Than, you can pass a variable to `awk`:

```
dir="dist/"
line=$(awk -v dir=$dir '/^[ \t]*$/{next} /^[ \t]*#/{next} {printf dir$2" "}' .file)
```